# Null value getting stored in mySQL table when insert query fired from ASP.NET using mySQL odbc connector

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

After spending several hours i am unable to figure out that why null values are being inserted into mySQL table using ASP.NET web page. I am using odbc connector for this.Below is the code for the same.

```
 public int Insert(string FirstName, string LastName, int age)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand odcmd_Insert = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO webuse(firstName,lastName,age) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)",conn);

    odcmd_Insert.Connection = conn;
    odcmd_Insert.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    try
    {

        odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter( "@param1", FirstName));
        odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter( "@param2", LastName));
        odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add( new OdbcParameter("@param3", age));

        return odcmd_Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    catch (OdbcException e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally {

        odcmd_Insert.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

}
```

I have debugged the code and all things seems well but all columns are updated with null values. Please help i am a noob to ASP.NET.

Comment: set the debug point and check either are you getting those values or not.

Comment: i have already checked all values are correctly recieved in the respective parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your OdbcCommand should be (replace in query `@paramN` with `?`)

```
OdbcCommand odcmd_Insert = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO webuse(firstName,lastName,age) VALUES(?,?,?)",conn);

odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter( "@param1", FirstName));
odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter( "@param2", LastName));
odcmd_Insert.Parameters.Add( new OdbcParameter("@param3", age));
```

Instead of the parameter it takes a ? in the CommandText (leave the name in the actual parameters param1,param2,param3)

Comment: same behavior in result?

Comment: look here http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/addparameterizedqueriesinmysqloledb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please try your argument like as below. I have used the MySqlConnection. you can use ODBC connection as well.

```
try
{
    // Connection string for a typical local MySQL installation
    string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=ci_series;Uid=root;Pwd=";

    // Create a connection object 
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);

    // Create a SQL command object
    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO webuse(firstName,lastName,age) VALUES(?param1,?param2,?param3)";


    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?param1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?param2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?param3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = age;

    connection.Open();

    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

The command should be as

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO webuse(firstName,lastName,age) VALUES(?param1,?param2,?param3)";
```

Comment: @neha ..Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069539/mysql-odbc-parameter-issue

Comment: The @param1 is actually being interpreted by MySQL as an undefined server-side variable, hence the "cannot be null" error.

Comment: odbc only understands "?" as the parameter. this was the error